# with object create function stor

Tags: javascript

Create function stor:
function works with next pattern:

```
const ourStorage = stor();
ourStorage.setValue('name', 'Miki');
ourStorage.setValue('age', 16);
ourStorage.getValue('name'); // Miki
ourStorage.getValue('age'); // 16
ourStorage.setValue('age', 20);
ourStorage.getValue('age'); // 20
ourStorage.getValue('occupation'); // undefined
```

im a little not understand how it make with using `setValue` and `getValue`

```
function stor() {
 const propsStorage = stor();
 ...
}
```

Comment: try like this,  ourStorage.setValue('occupation','Khrystyna');  you are getting undefined bcs you didnt set it.

Comment: What do you mean with `im a little not understand how it make with using setValue and getValue` do you mean that your task is to implement `getValue` and `setValue` and you don't know how?

Comment: So `stor` should return two methods when you call it. That should be the first thing you figure out. After that you should worry about setting a value and then fetching it.

Comment: @t.niese I don't know how implement function stor, function works with next pattern like I described above